# Issue with decompiled broken VB program

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm getting an issue with a line of code in a broken program I decompiled to fix. I fixed most of the issues but this one line is giving me an issue:

```
      new Thread(a0 => new VB$AnonymousDelegate_0(() => this.RunThreads())()).Start();
```

VB$AnonymousDelegate_0 seems to be giving an the problem but I have no idea how to fix this, coming from a background in Java.

Comment: Can you show error that you catch while compiling/running this piece of code?

Comment: I'm getting multiple errors: ; expected, A new expression requires (),[],{} after type, invalid expression term ), the type or namespace name VB could not be found. I feel like the decompiler is putting in a generic object name but I'm not sure what to insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decompiled code in C# (without using anonymous delegate) should look like this, but the decompiler did not do a good job.

```
new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(SomeMethod)).Start();
```

Where SomeMethod looks like

```
public void SomeMethod(object o)
{
    this.RunThreads();
}

private void RunThreads()
{
   //do actual work on new thread
}
```

Since no parameter is actually passed to the new thread, you don't have to use ParameterizedThreadStart delegate. Compiled code can be as simple as

```
new Thread(RunThreads).Start();
```

Comment: This is it. I was wondering what assembly code was doing there and thought it was a weird way to handle a thread.

Comment: @rufanov yes...I was trying to write code without using lambda expression, I think it is easier to understand since OP is new to C# syntax, lambda was a pain to me when I learnt it in .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a VB.NET code. It's C# code. Your decompiler is probably broken. This is how same code looks in VB.NET:

```
With New Thread(New ThreadStart(Sub() Me.RunThreads()))
    .Start()
End With
```

So there is new thread created, that will call `RunThreads` method of current class. And thread immediately started by .Start() method.

C# code is also little incorrect. It should like this:

```
new Thread(() => this.RunThread()).Start();
```